# How to use two primary keys into one foreign key?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, entity-relationship, relationship

```
mysql>   CREATE TABLE guests (
   ->   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ->   first_name varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
   ->   last_name  varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
   ->   email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   ->   role_type int(4) DEFAULT 4,
   ->   start_date  date,
   ->   expiry_date date,
   ->   reason blob,
   ->   added_by int(4) NOT NULL REFERENCES super_admins(id),
   ->   password_digest varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   ->   remember_token date DEFAULT NULL,
   ->   primary key(id),
   ->   CONSTRAINT fk_guests FOREIGN KEY(added_by) REFERENCES super_admins(id),
   ->   CONSTRAINT fk_guests1 FOREIGN KEY (added_by) REFERENCES admin(id)
   -> );
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. But from your question's title: you can not have two primary keys by definition of what primary key is

Comment: @AlmaDo I think he is trying to create a composite key using 2 primary keys from different tables.

Comment: CREATE TABLE super_admins (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name  varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  role_type int(4) DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE admins (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name  varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(100),
  role_type int(4) DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Comment: this are two tables i am linking to create a link which person added this guest account link using foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Polymorphic relationship (association). And you can't have a column (`added_by` in your case) that references two parent tables simultaneously. But what you can do to be able to use foreign key constraints is to have two nullable columns `added_by_super_admin` and `added_by_admin` only one of which will hold the value per record.

```sql
CREATE TABLE guests 
(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_name  VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  role_type INT(4) DEFAULT 4,
  start_date  DATE,
  expiry_date DATE,
  reason blob,
  added_by_super_admin INT(4) NULL,
  added_by_admin INT(4) NULL,
  password_digest VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  remember_token DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_guests  FOREIGN KEY (added_by_super_admin) REFERENCES super_admins(id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_guests1 FOREIGN KEY (added_by_admin) REFERENCES admin(id)
);
```

Then in queries you can do

```
SELECT ...
       COALESCE(s.id, a.id) added_by_id,
       COALESCE(s.name, a.name) added_by_name,
       ...
  FROM guests g LEFT JOIN super_admins s
    ON g.added_by_super_admin = s.id LEFT JOIN admin
    ON g.added_by_admin = a.id
```

Comment: that above your posted query showing this error message
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'backjobs.guests' (errno: 150)